# Car barely starts - low oil? Too late to fix or not?

Tags: engine, oil, seized-engine, low-oil

i think i have a probleem with my engine (Toyota Estima with 350.000km). It would not start, i just hear a single click. The battery is fine. I checked oil, and the oil is low. I tried starting the car a few times and suddenly it started turning over and started the car, with a lot of effort. It didn’t go smoothly. Driving afterwards went ok.
Is this because of the low oil and is it not too late to top it up?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest your starter is most likely at fault. Sounds like the brushes may be going out and bumping it (turning the key to the start position) enough times allows it to get to a spot where it will turn correctly. You may want to take it down to a parts store and get it tested. Your oil being a little low will NOT cause the issues you're talking about.

Comment: Hmm, will repairing the starter be expensive? Are you sure it’s not the oil? The oil is really low, like below the LOW mark. When the car finally manages to start the engine makes a very weak sound. Like it barely starts and could stall as well.

Comment: By the way, what I forgot to mention is that the car has a blown head gasket since a month or 2. I think it’s just slightly blown, it’s driving fine but I need to top up the coolant quite often. Maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: I just tried running the car again, but it won’t start now at all. I recorded the sound that it makes. I tried starting it for about 5 times now without succes. Here’s the sound that it makes: https://youtu.be/49E7qx7nycU

Comment: Top up the oil, fit new starter and fix the head gasket  give it a full service as well.

Comment: Are you doing this work yourself? If not you should consider whether the repairs are more than the value of the car 350,000km (218,000mi) is very high mileage.